# Line insertions and spacing with Google Sheets formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in the following format:

[image: Current]

In text form:

```
In/Out  Category    Sub-Category    Amount
In  In A    In A.1  100
In  In A    In A.2  20
In  In B    In B.1  500
Out Out C   Out C.1 20
Out Out D   Out D.1 50
Out Out D   Out D.2 10
Out Out D   Out D.3 15
Out Out E   Out E.1 45
Out Out F   Out F.1 5
Out Out F   Out F.2 110
```

I would like to display it in the following format:

[image: Desired]

Preferably with built in formulas and **not** custom made functions.
The "Totals" column is not as important. I can do that separately fairly easily. It is more the removal of the repetitions and insertions of rows that I am after.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(one,wraprows(,1,),null,wraprows(,4,),Σ,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),data,
    reduce(A1:D1,sequence(counta(Σ)),lambda(a,c,{a;
                {index(Σ,c),wraprows(,2,),sumif(A:A,index(Σ,c),D:D)};
                let(Δ,unique(filter(B:B,A:A=index(Σ,c))),reduce(wraprows("null_",4,),sequence(counta(Δ)),lambda(x,y,{x;{one,index(Δ,y),one,sumif(B:B,index(Δ,y),D:D)};
                let(Γ,filter(C:D,B:B=index(Δ,y)),Ξ,counta(choosecols(Γ,1)),{makearray(Ξ,2,lambda(r,c,iferror(1/0))),Γ});
                null})))})),
    filter(data,index(data,,1)<>"null_"))
```

[image]

Comment: That is one crazy but amazing formula! It does exactly what I asked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

`=LET(data,A:D,cdata,INDEX(data,2,1):INDEX(data,MAX(ROW(data)*(MMULT(N(data<>""),{1;1;1;1})=4))),io,INDEX(cdata,,1),cat,INDEX(cdata,,2),scat,INDEX(cdata,,3),amt,INDEX(cdata,,4),IFNA(REDUCE(INDEX(data,1),UNIQUE(io),LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(c,VSTACK({"","",SUMIF(io,c,amt)},LET(_,REDUCE(,UNIQUE(FILTER(cat,io=c)),LAMBDA(_a,_c,VSTACK(_a,HSTACK(_c,VSTACK({"",SUMIF(cat,_c,amt)},FILTER({scat,amt},cat=_c),))))),FILTER(_,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_))>1)))))))))`

Comment: It is a nice looking formula but it doesn't seem to fully work. At the moment I only have 1 "In" row. This row is placed at the end with the amount = 0 and none values for "In/Out", "Category" and "Sub". It just displays 2 rows with 3 first columns empty and 4th column is zero.

Comment: On a closer look and tests, it seems to be placing part of the first line as headings in the result.